# Updating caption in plot within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a Shiny app that shows a plot using `scatterD3` package. The plot contains a title and text that need to change as users select `a` or `b` with `selectInput`.

Here's an example app

```
library(shiny)
library(scatterD3)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           selectInput("choose", "Choose", choices = c("a", "b"))
    ), 
    column(7, offset = 0, scatterD3Output("plot"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  choosing = reactive(input$choose)

  plot.text = reactive({
    if(choosing() == "a") {
      paste("Title for a ")
    } else if (choosing() == "b") {
      paste("Title for b ")
    }
  })

  title = reactive(
    if(choosing() == "a") {
      paste("Text for ", input$choose)
    } else if (choosing() == "b") {
      paste("Text for ", input$choose)
    }
  )

  output$plot = renderScatterD3({
    scatterD3(data = mtcars, x = mpg, y = disp,
              point_size = 100, point_opacity = 0.5,
              hover_size = 3, hover_opacity = 1,
              color = "purple",
              caption = list(text = plot.text(),
                             title = title()),
              transitions = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The plot title and text don't change when I select either of the choices from the input control. I tried putting `input$choose` in `paste` directly as well as using `reactive` function as shown in example.

I don't know how to make caption interactive and I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Hi damir, interesting question! I'm pretty sure this is a bug of the scatterD3 package. You should create an issue [there](https://github.com/juba/scatterD3) and hope it gets picked up.

Comment: If you set `transitions = FALSE`, your code works.

Comment: Thanks, @Bas. I just opened an [issue](https://github.com/juba/scatterD3/issues/86).

Comment: @Bas is right that it was a bug in scatterD3 package. It has been resolved [here](https://github.com/juba/scatterD3/issues/86).